# Why is the actual map from Google Maps API not displaying on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a simple map to load onto HTML page.  I'm seeing all the navigation features like satellite/map buttons, zoom buttons and the street-view drop guy but no actual map is rendering.  Any ideas on what may be causing the short circuit?

I've tried to simplify the code to the simplest version found on Google's API documentation and I've tried different API keys. Same result.

```
<style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  function myMap() {
    let mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.12085),
      zoom: 5
    };
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);
  }
</script>

<script async
  defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######&callback=myMap"></script>
```

I would expect a working map to appear showing these coordinates.  Instead seeing navigation features like satellite/map buttons, zoom buttons and the street-view drop guy but no actual map is rendering.

Comment: Did you checked the developers console, if there is some error ?

Comment: It looks like [it's working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/d870j93s/) when I replace `######` with an actual Google Maps [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key). Can you check your console and update the question with any errors you might be getting? Also note `zoom: 5` is a very large scale. The only thing you could drop the street-view guy on is a country at that scale. Try `12`.

Answer (score -1):

There are options to disable navigation features like satellite/map buttons zoom here is an example

```
zoom: 5,        
fullscreenControl: false,
minZoom: 2,
streetViewControl: false,
clickableIcons: false
```

also see the [documentation][1]

if map is not rendering you have to see the console.. or share the console error message and also screenshot of what you are getting.

here is a full working code for your reference
see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s39pwz7q/

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.11111,-118.57056);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: myLatLng,
             //streetViewControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
                 clickableIcons: false,
                 styles: [
                    {
                      "featureType": "administrative",
                      "elementType": "geometry",
                      "stylers": [
                        {
                          "visibility": "off"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "featureType": "poi",
                      "stylers": [
                        {
                          "visibility": "off"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "featureType": "road",
                      "elementType": "labels.icon",
                      "stylers": [
                        {
                          "visibility": "off"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "featureType": "transit",
                      "stylers": [
                        {
                          "visibility": "off"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: "California Correctional Institution"
            });

Also there are some options which api does not give option to hide for that you can simply hide using css see below



    <style>
       .gm-style > button.gm-fullscreen-control{
         display:none;
        }
     </style>


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
  [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/s39pwz7q/
```